# Can we find an example of non-mesuarable set which their outer measure could be computed?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

We know there is non-measuarable set and we know every set has outer measure, so can anyone give me an example of a non-measuarable and there outer measure could be computed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider the Lebesgue (outer) measure on $[0,1]$ and let $V\subset [0,1]$ be a [Vitali set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set). Then $V$ is not measurable and for any measurable set $E\subset V$, $E$ is a measure-zero set.

Note that $[0,1]\setminus V$ is non-measurable and for every $a\in [0,1]$, $[0,a]\setminus V$ has outer-measure $a$. As a result, there exists $a_0\in[0,1)$, such that 
$$\{a\in [0,1] : [0,a]\setminus V \text{ is measurable }\}=[0,a_0].$$
Consequently, for every $a\in(a_0,1]$,  $[0,a]\setminus V$ is non-measurable with outer-measure $a$.

**Remark:** I guess $a_0=0$, but I have no idea how to prove or disprove it.

Comment: I have two question concern to your answer, first how $[0,a]\V$ is non-measurable ( I know the construction of Vitali set ). second how do you compute the outer measure of it to be equal to $a$. thanks

Comment: @kardohenry: Sorry, I didn't consider your first question carefully. Now I am not sure whether $[0,a]\setminus V$ is non-measurable or not. For the second question, no matter $[0,a]\setminus V$ is measurable or not, its out measure must be $a$, because otherwise, $[0,a]\cap V$ would contain a measurable subset with positive measure, which is absurd. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @kardohenry: Are you satisfied with the current version of my answer? At least $[0,1]\setminus V$ provides an example you want.

Comment: Thank you. your example work.

Comment: @kardohenry: You are welcome.